Layout styles not persisting on refresh
When I change styles at the overall root level using the layout.tsx file, it works.
When I add a layout.tsx file at a path level, the change shows up when I make the change during hot reload.
But when I manually refresh the page, or stop/start the app, or yarn build && yarn start, the style is no longer there. Why?
Using Next js version: 14.2.3.
The layout file at this position works for styles across all pages.
src
  app
    (main)
      page.tsx
    (auth)
      login
        page.tsx
  layout.tsx

But when I target it for specific paths as follows, change in style only shows up once during hot reload.
src
  app
    (main)
      page.tsx
    (auth)
      login
        page.tsx
        layout.tsx // adding styles here only shows once during hot reload
      register
        page.tsx
        layout.tsx // adding styles here only shows once during hot reload
    layout.tsx // adding styles here only shows once during hot reload
  layout.tsx // for testing, no styles here now. Will work if I add styles here.

Pages are very basic.
This is the layout file at root level which always works.
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Open_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import React from "react";

const font = Open_Sans({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "App",
  description: "App description",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`text-3xl ${font.className}`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

This is the layout that works once only during the first hot reload.
(I've tried copying exact above layout too, same result)
import React from "react";

const AuthLayout = ({
  children,
}: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <html lang="en">
    <body className="bg-amber-400 text-center mt-4">
      {children}
    </body>
  </html>
);
export default AuthLayout

Contents of all the page components. Only difference is the name of component.
const LoginPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          Login
        </div>
    );
};
   
export default LoginPage;


Nested layouts inherit the layout from the layout files above.
/layout
/dir/layout <-- inherits the layout from /layout
/dir/subdir/layout <-- inherits the layout from /layout and /dir/layout

Every document can only have one HTML/head/body element. If multiple instances are included, your DOM tree would look like this when generated:
<html>
  <body class="...">
    <html>
       <body class="...">
       </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>

If multiple HTML, head or body tags are present in the DOM tree, the browser will combine them into one, and the results may be as unexpected as what you get right now.
Refer to the documentation on nested layouts for more information, and use any other node (like a simple <div>) besides HTML/body or head in the nested layout files.
